gdalwarp on large rasters in S3
I am doing raster clipping with a shape from Geojson. Below is a code snippet. I need to clip 15 rasters (each of size 5GB). At present, the rasters are stored locally on my machine. I am planning to store these in S3. I am aware we can open file from S3 using vsis3_streaming - a file system handler that allows on-the-fly sequential reading of files available in AWS S3 buckets, without prior download of the entire file.
How do I update/modify the below method to perform raster clip from S3 efficiently. I do need a clipped raster (output) for further computation on the workflows.
def clip_raster(clip_polygon: str, raster: str) -> str:
try:
    raster_path = Path(raster)
    out_raster = raster.replace(raster_path.suffix, f"_Clipped{raster_path.suffix}")
    command = f"gdalwarp  -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:5070 -of GTiff -cutline {clip_polygon} -crop_to_cutline {raster} {out_raster}"
    result = os.system(command)
    if result != 0:
        raise Exception("gdalwarp command failed")
    if not os.path.exists(out_raster):
        raise Exception("Clipped raster does not exist")
    return out_raster
except Exception as e:
    return None
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


You didn't say what format your input file is, but here are a couple of things which might help:

if it's a GeoTIFF, you should use the tiled mode (i.e. gdal_translate -co TILED=YES) or COG, which will speed up reading of rectangular areas; other formats like Zarr are natively tiled. Make sure to save the output as tiled, too.
gdalwarp is slower than gdal_translate; you can use gdal_translate -projwin to crop the input to the bounding box of your cutline, rasterize the cutline (using gdal_rasterize), then apply it as a mask using gdal_calc.py
I haven't used vsicurl_streaming, but if you need to seek, vsicurl will be faster, especially for tiled files

These will matter most if your cutline is considerably smaller than the raster's extent.

Thank you @Gradeshade., The input format is TIFF. This is raster file for entire US. I am clipping small polygon and calculating all pixel values of clipped raster.  I want to read the input TIFF from S3 and do clipping.

In that case, my suggestion to use tiled rasters should work pretty well. Let me know if you give it a try.
